# How do I format a tree so that it works with Clojure's zipper?

Tags: clojure, tree, genetic-programming, zipper

I am creating trees of s-expressions for a genetic programming problem, and need to alter parts of the trees during the evolution process. I came across the [Clojure zipper](http://clojure.org/other_libraries) function that seems like it should be perfect, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to use it.

For example, say I create a zipper with

```
(def zipped (zip/seq-zip `(+ (- 1 2) 3)))
```

I understand this to represent a tree with + at the root, one that looks like this:

```
   +
 -   3
1 2
```

My zipper, though, doesn't agree with this: If I ask for the first node with `(-> zipped zip/down zip/node)` it gives me `+` (which is correct) but it `(-> zipped zip/down zip/down)` doesn't take me to `-`, instead it returns `nil`. Indeed, `(-> zipped zip/down zip/rights)` gives the rest of the tree as siblings to the right of the root, which suggests to me that I don't have a tree at all:

```
user> (-> zipped zip/down zip/rights)
((clojure.core/- 1 2) 3)
```

I'm pretty sure I'm representing my trees correctly because when I execute them I get the right answer. Does zipper expect a different layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there are two different ideas of tree going on here. Your tree is a graph of how the values percolate through the evaluation, but LISP is thinking about lists of lists, and using prefix notation:

'(+ (- 1 2) 3) is also (list + (list - 1 2) 3), which is actually this tree:

```
+  .     3
   - 1 2
```

`(-> zipped down node)` gives you the first element, +, an atom.
`(-> zipped down down)` thus gives you nil because the first element, +, is an atom.
`(-> zipped down right down node)` gives you the minus sign you want because that's the first element of the second element of the expression.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, it cleared things up for me. I don't think I need to traverse the tree in the order in which it's executed, so I can probably still use Zipper.

Answer (score 1):

The tree isn't how you've diagrammed it. The root node has 3 children: `+`, `(- 1 2)`, and `3`.  When you do `down` from the root node, it defaults to the left-most child, hence why you see `+`.

To get to the `-` you'd need to call:

```
user=> (-> zipped zip/down zip/right zip/down zip/node)
clojure.core/-
```